# jQuery autocomplete servlet retun values

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, autocomplete

for a Java Servlet project I need to create an autocomplete.
So I am using the jQuery autocomplete plugin.
It is embed in a jsp file 'autocomplete.jsp'

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function(){
$("#username").autocomplete("/Servlet/AutoComplete");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<br><br><center>


Select Username   :
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>

</font>
</body>
</html>
```

and AutoComplete.java is a Servlet:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   try{
     String s[]=null;

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=");
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM database.datatable");

       List li = new ArrayList();

       while(rs.next())
       {
           li.add(rs.getString(1));
       }

       String[] str = new String[li.size()];
       Iterator it = li.iterator();

       int i = 0;
       while(it.hasNext())
       {
           String p = (String)it.next();
           str[i] = p;
           i++;
       }

    //jQuery related start
       String query = (String)request.getParameter("q");

       int cnt=1;
       for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
       {
           if(str[j].toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
           {
              System.out.print(str[j]+"\n");
              if(cnt>=5)// 5=How many results have to show while we are typing(auto suggestions)
              break;
              cnt++;
            }
       }
    //jQuery related end

rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();

}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

So currently, the results are printed in the Tomcat Output inside the IDE.
Which is pretty nice to know, but the user does not see it.
I tried to change the `System.out.print(str[j]+"\n");` line into

```
return str[j];
```

But this did not help me too. I think I need to add something into the autocomplete.jsp file. But I have no idea, what to do there.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.print` only prints to your console.  You do need to print the values, but you need to print them to the servlet response.  (You can't just `return` java objects from a servlet to javascript.)

Before `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");` add:

```
java.io.PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
```

Then change `System.out.print(` to `writer.write(`